# Rails .each for db rows containing a certain parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, each, parameters

Apologies if this has been asked before, I may have been searching for the wrong keywords.

I am trying to do an `.each` loop for all the rows of a database table named `users` for which `name` equals `user1`. How is that done?

My model **User** has a DB Table :users that contains these columns: `name | title | details | amount`

In my view I have this:

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left">
<h3>User1</h3>
<% @User1.each do |i| %>
  <p><%= i.title %></p>
  <p><%= i.details %></p>
  <p>$<%= i.amount %></p>
<% end %>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;float:left">
<h3>User2</h3>
  <% @User2.each do |i| %>
  <p><%= i.title %></p>
  <p><%= i.details %></p>
  <p>$<%= i.amount %></p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

For my controller I have this but it is giving an error:

```
@items = User.all
@User1 = @items.where(name: 'user1')
@User2 = @items.where(name: 'user2')
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. :) What is @item?

Comment: Sorry, edited. I had the wrong instance variables written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over an array of users matching those in a given list, use

in your controller:

```
 @users = User.where(name: list_of_names)
```

where `list_of_names` is an array of strings,

and, in your view:

```
 <% @users.each_with_index do |user, idx| %>
    <div id="user-<%= idx %>">
       <%= user.name %>
       <%= user.details %>
        # etc
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

and etc.

See the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) for more.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't exactly what I'm trying to do. On the view I have 2 columns(divs). The left column lists all the items for user1 and the right column lists all the items for user2. I want to iterate over the user model and filter the content of the loop on the left column to only list the db rows that contain the :name parameter for that user(user1) and vice versa on the right column for user2.

Comment: I don't think it's advisable to iterate over the entire database table in the view. It would be much more efficient pull the required data in the controller layer and only pass what you need to the view.

Comment: I've modified the above for an arbitrary number of users. The positioning can be accomplished with some CSS.

Comment: This is brilliant and will allow me to expand it later on if need be. Unfortunately it seems to be seeing list_of_names as a local variable and giving me an error. undefined local variable or method `list_of_names' for #<UsersController:0x007fed62508230>

Comment: `list_of_names` is just a local variable for an array of strings, so you'll have to define it with the desired strings before you use it, or you can just replace it with an array of strings :)

Comment: Oops! I should haven known that. Thanks so much for you help jmromer!

Answer (score 0):

`@user1 = User.where(name: "name1").first`

`@user2 = User.where(name: "name2").first`

Is that what you want?

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for but when I tried this and replaced "name1" with the correct string it still gave me an error saying:  syntax error, unexpected '<'
<% @user1.each do |i| @output_buffer.safe_append='